# How to find a specific word in CSV column and write its position into the next column using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

How to find a specific word in a column and write its position in next column in Python.

For example I have a CSV File

And I want to find a "(correct)" word and then put its position in next column, and continue to loop through whole file like this.

[image]

In this example, banana has word "(correct)" and is in 3rd in column so G is edited as 3.

And the same goat has the word "(correct)" so we added 4 in G column

Also replace the "(correct)" with empty string after each loop

Answer (score 0):

Without more sample data to test, and if all you want is a really quick  solution to get you started... see below.

```
with open(csvfile) as csvf:   # open csv file
    lines = csvf.read().split("\n")  # split contents into lines
    for i, line in enumerate(lines): 
        row = line.split(",")   #  split lines into columns
        for j, col in enumerate(row):   
            if "(correct)" in col:   # check if keyword in column
                row.append(str(j))   # append the row to last column 
        lines[i] = ','.join(row)     

with open(csvfile, 'wt') as csvfw:
    csvfw.write('\n'.join(lines))    # write lines back to file.
```

There is also the `csv` module in the python stdlib you may want to check out.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv