# Extract particular word from 'remarks' column in a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, extract

I have a csv input file 'out_test.csv' which has a remarks column. I want to extract 'aaaa' from there and also +- 1 word with 'aaaa' being the centre. Then need to add an additional column named 'info' and store those 3 words there. Here is the file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TSte.png)

Note: 'aaaa' may not be there in the column, in that case write 'NA' in the 'info' column.

I have already done this:

```
with open('out_test.csv','r+') as csvf:   # open csv file
    lines = csvf.read().split("\n")  # split contents into lines
    for i, line in enumerate(lines): 
        row = line.split(",")   #  split lines into columns
        for j, col in enumerate(row):   
            if "aaaa" in col:   # check if keyword in column
                row.append(str(j))   # append the row to last column 
        lines[i] = ','.join(row)     

with open('out_test.csv', 'wt') as csvfw:
    csvfw.write('\n'.join(lines))    # write lines back to file.
```

Note:

1. I took reference from another post here with more or less the same question. [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72281339/how-to-find-a-specific-word-in-csv-column-and-write-its-position-into-the-next-c)
2. I am also getting some permission error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way :

```
import csv, re

WORD, N = "aaaa", 1

pattern = (
    rf"((?:\S+ +){{0,{N}}}\S*"  # word(s) before target
    rf"\b{re.escape(WORD)}\b"   # the targeted word
    rf"\S*(?: +\S+){{0,{N}}})"  # word(s) after target
)

with open("input.csv", "r") as inpf, open("output.csv", "w") as outf:

    data = [
        {**line, "info": re.search(pattern, line["remarks"]).group()
        if re.search(pattern, line["remarks"]) else "NA"}
        for line in csv.DictReader(inpf)
    ]

    writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/uQGitL/1)]

Or with an equivalent from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) (*using the same* `pattern` *as above*) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

(
    pd.read_csv("input.csv")
      .assign(info=lambda x: x["remarks"]
              .str.extract(pattern, expand=False).fillna("NA"))
      .to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
)
```

Last 2 fields of `output.csv` (*in a tabular format*) :

```
                                       remarks                  info
0  xxxyyyy zzzz aaaa bbbb ccc dd erfdefgrgesrg        zzzz aaaa bbbb
1  xxxyyyy zzzz aaaa bbbb ccc dd erfdefgrgesrg        zzzz aaaa bbbb
2                   aaaa bbbbb wwww dddd zzzzz            aaaa bbbbb
3  xxxyyyy zzzz aaaa bbbb ccc dd erfdefgrgesrg        zzzz aaaa bbbb
4  xxxyyyy zzzz aaaa bbbb ccc dd erfdefgrgesrg        zzzz aaaa bbbb
5            chuifheurfhr asbfswgfduwsegf aaaa  asbfswgfduwsegf aaaa
6                        loezlerl oooezp bbbll                    NA
```

Used `input.csv` :

```
id,f_name,1_name,fc_id,remarks
1,Raj,Sharma,1,xxxyyyy zzzz aaaa bbbb ccc dd erfdefgrgesrg
1,Raj,Sharma,2,xxxyyyy zzzz aaaa bbbb ccc dd erfdefgrgesrg
1,Raj,Sharma,2,aaaa bbbbb wwww dddd zzzzz
2,Ram,Kapoor,1,xxxyyyy zzzz aaaa bbbb ccc dd erfdefgrgesrg
2,Ram,Kapoor,2,xxxyyyy zzzz aaaa bbbb ccc dd erfdefgrgesrg
3,Raju,Verma,3,chuifheurfhr asbfswgfduwsegf aaaa
4,XXXX,Yyyyy,4,loezlerl oooezp bbbll # <-- added by me
```

***UPDATE*** :

If you need target more than a word, you can try the pattern below :

```
WORDS, N = ["aaaa", "tttt"], 1

pattern = (
    rf"((?:\S+ +){{0,{N}}}\S*"
    fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, WORDS))})\b"
    rf"\S*(?: +\S+){{0,{N}}})"
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Timeless, it worked. Sorry I don't know how to directly reply to your comment. 
If it's not an issue, is there a way I can include variations of my target word?
For eg: aaaa could be Aaaa or aaAa or AaAa or aAAA etc.
Again, thank you for taking time to answer this query.

Comment: @Fanatic, no worries, a priori, the pattern can handle that. You just need to add `flags=re.IGNORECASE` as an argument to  `re.search` and to `str.extract` (*if using the pandas approach*).

Comment: Hey @Timeless, sorry for bothering you again. Although I understood the re.IGNORECASE solution, what I meant was that let's say my target word is not only 'aaaa' but also 'tttt'. 
I know the example input file does not have that but that's my fault. So if I want to multiple target words, what should I do? I tried to create a list but did not work. Please note that 2 target words won't be together in the same row, so either 'aaaa' will be there or 'tttt'.
If you could kindly help me out, that would be great.

Comment: @Fanatic, no problem. I added an update to the answer. Can you check it out ?